# Compare an int with an number stored in a dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries and in it I have a key value that is an Integer, I would like to compaire this keyvalue against another int like so...

```
while ([myInt != [[sortedArray valueForKey:@"MODID"] objectAtIndex:count]]) {
```

The plan is that i loop though the array of dictionary until I find an entry that matches they i pass the count value over to where I need to use it.

However I am getting this as my warning.... and then when its executed it never finds a value that matches..

```
Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'id')
```

and I also get a error on the same line

```
Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot store a primitive in a dictionary. So you will never be able to correctly compare like that. What is happening there is you are comparing an address for an object with an it. very unlikely to match.

Use the following to get the integer value for the dictionary object

```
while (myInt != [[[sortedArray valueForKey:@"MODID"] objectAtIndex:count] integerValue]) {
```

I would go for something like this, based on what i can tell of your data structure.

```
for(NSDictionary *d in sortedArray){
    NSArray *subarray = [d objectForKey:@"MODID"];
    for(int i=0; i<[subarray count]; i++){
        if( [[subarray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] == myInt){
             //you have found it, do whatever you need, and break from the loop
         }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to use use this and its working fine but it never finds a match for some reason.. and the count just goes outside the bounds of the array... so it never actually finds a match.

Comment: i would modify to look like something different. i'll edit my answer to give you an idea

Comment: I forgot to mention where you have == myInt I ended up going with a NSNumber so used **isEqualToNumber:myNumber]**

Comment: that is fine as well. They are functionally equivalent. I don't imagine the performance differences (minimal at best) would ever be noticeable, so it's just a matter of what you are comfortable with, and what style you use.  As a quick note though, I don't know if comparing an NSString of @"1" will be equivalent to an NSNumber with a value of 1. Whereas if you compare the integerValue of them they will be the same. Just something to be aware of i guess.

Answer (score 2):

The number in the array is stored in an NSNumber object. You need to get the `intValue` from the `NSNumber` object.

```
while (myInt != [[[sortedArray valueForKey:@"MODID"] objectAtIndex:count] intValue]) {
```

If you are using the latest LLVM compiler in Xcode 4.5 you can write that as:

```
while (myInt != [sortedArray[@"MODID"][count] intValue]) {
```

Edit: The shorthand notation won't actually work in this case. I overlooked the use of `valueForKey:` in the original code. I read it as `objectForKey:` thinking this was a dictionary with an array. But it's an array of dictionaries.

Comment: you have n error in your response (I had the same one in mine, from copy pasting his code). The first open [ is not needed.

Comment: I voted your answer up, because I didn't know you could do that trick with the LLVM compiler, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while ([myInt != [[[sortedArray valueForKey:@"MODID"] objectAtIndex:count] intValue])
```

instead. As you cannot store Integer value into array nor dictionary. It should be NSNumber or other type (which is `id` type either).

---

And by the way, shouldn't it be

```
while (myInt != [[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:count] valueForKey:@"MODID"] intValue])
```

instead? I find that `sortedArray` is an array.

Comment: oh right.. yes it is a number i just checked.. duh!! however I have tried your code and there is an issue with one of the brackets just after count

Comment: Okay cool thanks very much.. something weird is happening with my array now so I need to sort that out and I will hopefully end up using this... Thanks very much for your help. I will mark your answer as correct once i have done that.

Comment: For some odd reason its not breaking the while statement when the correct value is compared.

Comment: @HurkNburkS maybe all values do not equal to `myInt`. Set a breakpoint or NSLog during `while` statement to do checking.

Answer (score 0):

you are able to see those warnings because may be you are trying to refer to an object with an datatype like int.

```
for(NSDictionary *d in sortedArray){
    NSArray *subarray = [d objectForKey:@"MODID"];
    for(int i=0; i<[subarray count]; i++){
        if( [[subarray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] == myInt){
             //you have found it, do whatever you need, and break from the loop
         }
}
```

if you observe this line `[[subarray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]` you can undestand easily that an object is converted into int type and being used for comparision.